# Best way to DRY that and clarify code better

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm searching for the better way on keeping my controllers clean and readable. Take a look at this controller action :

```
  def start
    @work_hours = params[:work_hours].to_i

    redirect_to labor_url, :flash => {:error => I18n.t('error.invalid_post')} and return unless (1..8).include? @work_hours
    redirect_to labor_url, :flash => {:error => I18n.t('error.working')} and return if current_user.working?
    redirect_to labor_url, :flash => {:error => I18n.t('error.has_quest')} and return if current_user.has_tavern_quest?

    redirect_to labor_path 
  end
```

As you can see, these are doing the same thing if a condition happens. They are setting a flash message and redirecting to a url(and returning). While this seems ok to me in terms of clarification, i can't help but notice a bit of repetition in the redirects and i don't like setting flash[:error] with a translation in such an ugly manner.

Do you think this can be done in a better, DRYer and more readable way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the url is the same for all redirects (if i see correctly, no difference between url and path), so i would refactor that as follows:

```
def start
  @work_hours = params[:work_hours].to_i

  flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.invalid_post') unless (1..8).include? @work_hours
  flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.working') if current_user.working?
  flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.has_quest') if current_user.has_tavern_quest?

  redirect_to labor_path 
end
```

So: set the flash if needed, and redirect to `labor_path` in all cases. Does that help?

If in case of error you would need to redirect to something else, do something like:

```
def start
  @work_hours = params[:work_hours].to_i

  flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.invalid_post') unless (1..8).include? @work_hours
  flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.working') if current_user.working?
  flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.has_quest') if current_user.has_tavern_quest?

  redirect_to labor_error_path and return if flash[:error]
  redirect_to labor_path 
end
```

If conditions are not mutually exclusive, i would write it like this:

```
def start
  @work_hours = params[:work_hours].to_i

  flash[:error] = unless (1..8).include? @work_hours 
    I18n.t('error.invalid_post') 
  elsif current_user.working?
    I18n.t('error.working')
  elsif current_user.has_tavern_quest?
    I18n.t('error.has_quest') 
  else
    nil
  end

  redirect_to labor_error_path and return if flash[:error]
  redirect_to labor_path 
end
```

I am not entirely sure if the `else nil` is explicitly needed. Does this help?

Comment: Actually, i didn't mean to have the same urls,just didn't notice it, but you are certainly right as it is now. However, if the last redirect was to a different url, how would you handle it ?

Comment: yes, i was thinking something similar after i saw your first code. Thanx i think this is very good :)

Comment: Edited my answer. Normally when editing stuff, in case of error, you just render the page, and in case of success you redirect. In your case that is clearly not the case: it looks like an action on a page (start working), so I would even try to use ajax, since that is more responsive.

Comment: exactly, this is an action and i do have to take a look at using ajax there, you're right for sure. I haven't gotten my hands much dirty with ajax in Rails till now to be sincere, but i will definitely take a closer look.

Comment: I actually found an important problem. If 2 or more errors happen at the same time, the redirect will show the last flash error. Which can be ok, but heavily messes with rspec tests and general logic. Therefore, i'm probably going to use redirect_to explicitly again :/

Comment: So, i changed it to : "flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.invalid_post') and redirect_to melee_url('Weapon') and return unless GameItem.exists?(:id => item_id)"

Comment: Please don't put conditions at the end of lines. It makes people who have to maintain the project go crazy trying to read what you were doing.

Comment: @rxgx I disagree, it allows your code to read as a natural sentence, so for me it actually improves readability. But you will have to adapt your code-scanning abilities when coming from other languages.